# Isass.exe application error

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Basically, this is what happened - I was going to `youtube.com` and I was confronted with a message from `Avast! anti virus database`. It said

> malicious url is trying to infiltrate my computer

So I did a full anti virus scan and proceeded to restart my computer. After the windows xp loading screen was done, the screen flickered a couple times (which I thought was just my computer loading), but then a message pops up saying

> the `isass.exe` application error has occurred

Every time I reboot my computer, whether it is in safe mode or regular, the same message pops up, and judging by the previous comments on this forum, I would say that I need to re-install windows xp. Is there anything else that i can do?

Answer (score 0):

If the message says `lsass.exe` (lower-case "L"), then reinstalling Windows is the easiest way. LSASS is a core part of Windows and it would be very hard to fix it if Windows cannot boot.

(Your post says `isass.exe`. Which letter does the *actual message* start with – "i" or "L"?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try everything you can before resorting to a wipe and re-install, you could try a **system restore** and a **repair installation**.

The system restore (outside Windows) will restore the registry to a time when it was uninfected.  The repair installation will reset all the core system files and do away with any infected ones.

Of course, there is absolutely no guarantee that this will work.  Once viruses have taken root it's usually very difficult if not impossible to get rid of them.  System restore also has to have been switched on and remain uninfected.

Microsoft document doing the out-of-Windows system restore quite well on their website in [**KB307545**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545).  You boot into the recovery console using the XP installation CD and simply overwrite the live registry hives with those in the special system restore folder which is buried deep in a hidden folder.

As soon as you have carried this out, immediate boot into the XP installation CD again and proceed with the repair installation.  Also documented on Microsoft website under [**KB978788**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978788).  Method 2 is what I would recommend.  I.e. proceed to the screen after accepting the licence, highlight the existing installation from the list and press R.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is infected and Windows is damaged - don't use it. The following advice is only damage control, as the only good solution is to reformat the hard disk and reinstall Windows.

If you wish to restore the computer to semi-usability in order to save your stuff, here is some advice :

1. Use another computer to download and burn an anti-virus live CD and use it to boot and clean the infected computer. Some such CDs are [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk) and [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.avira.com/en/support-download-avira-antivir-rescue-system). **Don't** expect them to fully clean up the infection.
2. You could also take the disk out and insert it in another computer and use its anti-virus. You could also afterward copy this way your data from the disk, but be very careful not to infect the other computer : don't execute or open any file from the infected computer on this second computer, only copy to an external disk.
3. You could also [Perform a Windows XP Repair Install](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/operatingsystems/ss/instxprepair1.htm) to refresh Windows, but you need an XP boot CD that has your service-pack level. You cannot use an earlier boot CD.
4. If you feel up to it, you could try in extremity the very geeky
   [Performing a manual restore of the Windows XP registry](http://www.aitechsolutions.net/winxpnoboot.html), but this is really overdoing it.

Once your data is safe on an external disk :

1. Format the hard disk
2. Reinstall Windows
3. Run Windows Update as many times as required for it to be fully patched
4. Install a couple of anti-viruses and use them to scan the salvaged data. One of them should be [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/).
5. Restore the data.

Next time use Firefox with the [NoScript extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) to not let malicious websites execute their scripts on your computer. Certainly do not ever use Internet Explorer for surfing, especially not on XP.